# Firebase/Stripe getProducts returns an empty list

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I've created some products on Stripe which I can retrieve using

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/products   -u sk_test_...:   -G
```

I've installed stripe/firestore-stripe-payments@0.2.4 in Firebase https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments and configured it using the same secret test key

In my website, I use the corresponding web sdk https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/tree/master/firestore-stripe-web-sdk and have something like

```
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(firebaseApp);
  const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if (user) {
      console.log('Logged in as '+user.email );
    } else {
      console.log('No user');
    }
  });
  
  var userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, ..., ...)
  // Signed in 
  const user = userCredential.user;
    
  const payments = getStripePayments(firebaseApp, {
  productsCollection: "products",
  customersCollection: "customers",
  });
  console.log('#Payments ' + JSON.stringify(payments));

  const products = await getProducts(payments);
  console.log('#Products2 ' + products.length);

  const session = await createCheckoutSession(payments, {price: <a_hardcoded_priceId>,});
  window.location.assign(session.url);
```

The `createCheckoutSession` seems to work fine, and I do see in Firebase a `customers` collection and inside my customer, I see a `checkout_sessions` collection.

But the returned list of products is empty.
Any idea what might be wrong?
All products have type=service (which might be the root cause if https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2018-02-05 is still relevant) but not sure how I can change this.

Suggestions I could try?
Additional info I could provide?

Comment: Are the Product objects syncing to your Firestore collection from Stripe? Are you listening for the related `product.*` events in the Stripe webhook you configured?

Comment: I did not configure a webhook yet (did not read the https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/master/firestore-stripe-payments/POSTINSTALL.md yet).  That probably explains the behavior I'm observing!  I'll have a look at it and keep you posted!

Comment: After configuring the webhook, I indeed see the products!

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it.